# MongoDB insert into collection through CLI

Tags: javascript, mongodb, command-line-interface

I have a mongodb running on my development machine. I need to insert some documents into few collections before deploying the web app.

As in documentation, I use this code to create collection and to insert documents into it.

```
db.createCollection("usersTypes");
db.collection.insertMany({[
       { "_id":"1", "title":"Basic" },
       { "_id":"2", "title":"Premium" }
    ]},
    {
        writeConcern: "usersTypes",
        ordered: false
    });
```

To run the JS file that contains the insert statements I use this code on the command line:
`mongo mydb statements.js`

But I receive error `Syntax Error: missing ] in computed property name`

How should I fix my insert script so that I can populate mongo db collections with data?

Comment: `db.collection.insertMany( [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ] )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
> db.userTypes.insertMany([{ "_id":"1", "title":"Basic"},{ "_id":"2", "title":"Premium" }]);
{ "acknowledged" : true, "insertedIds" : [ "1", "2" ] }
```

you can specify the collection name after `db`.

you don't need curly braces around the first argument (just an array of documents is fine).

[write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) specifies how thoroughly (and slowly) writes are acknowledged

Comment: although your answer is correct, consider adding some more detailed information about why this code is working and what was wrong with the one in the question

Comment: nwm. you just did :)